# send email using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I already used AMPScript in my emails but now for some reason when I try to send an email using that I received the error "There was an error sending this Email."
I already reduce my code to test the send but the error still continue. At this moment I only use this:

```
%%[
Var @subscriberKey 
Set @subscriberKey = _subscriberKey 
]%%

%%= v(@subscriberKey) =%%
```

Any suggestion for what is happen?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I already found the resolution the problem is the spaces I had between lines, without any space in my code everything works very fine:

```
%%[Var @subscriberKey Set @subscriberKey = _subscriberKey ]%%
%%= v(@subscriberKey) =%%
```